# Change video id in youtube embed code with query value

Tags: php, javascript, youtube, embed

what I want to do basically, is to take the parameters from the html page and place it as video ID into the youtube embedded code, so when the page loads, it shows the embedded player of the corresponding video.

How I want it to work, is to have buttons on a web page that will link to a video.html page with the video id in parameters, and load the corresponding video.

I know I probably have to use javascript or php, but I don't know both of them so explain as clearly as possible please. So I want to replace "VIDEOID" with my query string as simply as possible.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/"VIDEOID" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this code to [get parameter value from url in html](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html)

Hope its helpful for you..